# Rotation of Higher order Tensors

Tags: matlab, tensor

I have a $D$-way tensor of dimensions $n\times n \times \dots \times n$ $(D)$- times. I want to sum the First vectors in all directions. For example, let $\boldsymbol{H}$ is 3-way tensor of dimensions $n \times n 
 \times n$. Then the desired output, $Res = \boldsymbol{H}(:,1,1)+\boldsymbol{H}(1,:,1)'+reshape(\boldsymbol{H}(1,1,:),n,1)$. How can I perform this automatically for higher dimensional tensors? I tried using rot90 function in MATLAB, but it rotates only the first slice of the Tensor.

```
H(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
H(:,:,2) = 10*[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
H(:,:,3) = 100*[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

Res = H(:,1,1)+H(1,:,1)'+reshape(H(1,1,:),3,1);
```

Here $Res = \begin{bmatrix}1\\4\\7 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1\\10\\100 \end{bmatrix}$

for higher dimensions:
$D=4, Res = H(:,1,1,1)+H(1,:,1,1)'+reshape(H(1,1,:,1),3,1)+reshape(H(1,1,1,:),3,1);$

and so on for
$D=5,6,..$. I do not want to do this summation manually.

Comment: Here's how I'd do it in Julia (which has fast for-loops)
$$\eqalign{
&{\tt res = zeros(n)} \\
&{\tt for\;k=1:n} \\
&\qquad {\tt res[k] = H[k,1,1,1] + H[1,k,1,1] + H[1,1,k,1] + H[1,1,1,k]} \\
&{\tt end}
}$$

Comment: Hi Greg. Thank you. The line inside the for loop is only for 4-way tensor. Is there a way to do it for any dimensional tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the permute function I guess you might be able to do something like this, for the example that you have given with `H` is a $3\times 3\times 3$ tensor, which has the vector dimension and tensor dimension as $3$,

```
nTensorDim = 3;
nVectorDim = 3;

sz = size(H);
inds = repmat({1},1,ndims(H));
inds{1} = 1:sz(1);

sum = zeros(nVectorDim, 1);
for i=1:nTensorDim
    idx = 1:nTensorDim;
    idx(i) = 1;
    idx(1) = i;
    y = permute(H, idx);
    sum = sum + y(inds{:});
end
```

The variable `sum` would contain the result. Hope this is the tensor operation that you have explained!

Comment: Hi Thank you, but what is populateX() function and what is the variable 'n' inside the for loop?

Comment: I edited my question with an example. I am trying to sum the first vectors in all directions of a higher order array. Thus, the resulting summed variable is a vector of size same as the size of the tensor, i.e. size n of a nxnxn tensor.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I guess the code snippet should work for the example you have given, I have edited the answer again.

Comment: Can this be extended for higher order tensors, where I can sum the rest of the elements of the tensor H? Can you please refer to this for clarification? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4718760/706629

Answer (score 2):

Julia has a convenient "..." (aka splat) operator,
which deconstructs a vector into a list, so you can do this

```
s = zeros(n)        # sum accumulates in this vector
ndx = ones(Int,D)   # set every index to 1 (or 2, or 3)
for k = 1:D
    x = ndx[k]
    for j = 1:n
        ndx[k] = j  # set kth index to j
        s[j] = s[j] + H[ndx...]  # SPLAT
    end
    ndx[k] = x    # reset kth index
end
```

The above algorithm can be trivially modified to calculate the sum the **second** vector from each dimension by initializing `ndx` to a vector of $2$s, or the **third** vectors with a vector of $3$s, etc.

I'm not a Matlab guy, but it must have something equivalent to the splat operator.

### Update

Here's a modification which uses a symbolic colon (at the end of the `ndx` array) to vectorize the inner loop

```
s, ndx = zeros(n), [ones(Int,D)..., :]
for k = 1:D
    x, ndx[k] = ndx[k], ndx[end]
    s, ndx[k] = s+H[ndx[1:D]...], x
end
```

While it has a nicer appearance, it's actually 400% ***slower*** than the previous version.

Comment: Can this be extended for higher order tensors, where I can sum the rest of the elements of the tensor H? Can you please refer to this for clarification? math.stackexchange.com/q/4718760/706629